# Can't get Tensorflow Version > 0.11 on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, conda

Setting:

- Raspberry Pi 3 (B+) running Raspbian Stretch with ARMv7 cpu
- BerryConda Python 3.6 environment

On Raspberry pi, I can't seem to install a tensorflow version newer than `0.11` (at time of writing, `1.12` is the newest tensorflow version).  If I `pip install tensorflow` (after upgrading pip of course) I get `0.11`:

[image]

If I try to force it to install a newer version, I get a `tensorflow-1.11.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform` error:

[image]

Looking at the [list of wheels in piwheels for tensorflow](https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/) it seems that `0.11` is the only one that works for "any" architecture, so that must have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The userland for Raspbian [is still 32-bit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61785/is-there-a-specific-download-for-64-bit-raspbian). Given the limited amount of memory, it doesn't make much sense to use a 64-bit userland.

I doubt if a wheel made for Python 3.5 would work with Python 3.6, but you might try `tensorflow-1.11.0-cp35-none-linux_armv6l.whl`.

As a last resort, you could try building it yourself; you might want to use an USB harddisk or SSD for that purpose, though.

A raspberry Pi does seem somewhat underpowered for tensorflow... Running it on a desktop PC (*especially* if you have a powerful GPU and a tensorflow that can take advantage of that) should be significantly faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm a bit novice at this stuff, so I do not understand what the original problem has to do with 32 vs 64 bit.

Comment: @Peter The Pi 3B+ actually has an ARMv8 (64-bit) CPU. Both ARMv6 and ARMv7 are 32-bit.

Comment: Ah, really? When I run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` I get `model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)`...

Comment: @Peter That's odd. That contradicts the [official specs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/).

Comment: huh, odd indeed.  It does say Model 3 B+ right on the board

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you're going to have to try and build your own tensorflow. Good luck!